# How to stop specific amount of threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I would like to stop/kill N thread when I receive a socket event.
I don't find any way to do that with my current app structure.

Here is the code to start threads :

```
for i in range(news_viewers):
    t = threading.Thread(target=bot, args=(i + 1,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.name = "Viewer"
    t.start()
```

When I receive the event I would like to kill/stop N thread named **Viewer** on my list :

```
for i in range(number_of_threads_to_kill):
    #number_of_threads_to_kill is received by sockerIO
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        if 'Viewer' in t.getName():
            #I NEED TO CLOSE N THREAD HERE
            print('CLOSE THIS THREAD')
```

I can't find a way to do it, I tried many things but none of them worked.

threading.enumerate() return this :

```
.., <Thread(Viewer, started daemon 41868)>, <Thread(Viewer, started daemon 53872)>, <Thread(Viewer, started daemon 54748)>, <Thread(Viewer, started daemon 50028)>,...
```

Can someone help me to setup that ?

Comment: In real-life you should avoid abruptly `stop`-ping threads even when there is such operation: you can never really know what the thread is doing at the moment, what kind of resources it may leak, and the like. The first approach should alway be to notify the thread to stop its operation. As your threads get their indices, you could use a list of [`Event`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects), then the threads could periodically check their flag and exit when requested. If you want to actually wait for a thread to exit afterwards, use its `join()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to close thread.

When I start a thread I add the id of the thread in threads_ids array  :

```
global stop_ids, threads_ids
for i in range(news_viewers):
    tid = random.randint(1, 1000)
    threads_ids.append(tid)
    t = threading.Thread(target=bot, args=(tid,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.name = "Viewer"
    t.start()
```

When I want to close a Thread I add the N first id on stop_ids array :

```
global stop_ids, threads_ids
n = threads_ids[:number_of_thread_to_close]
stop_ids = stop_ids + n
```

On my bot function I check every N second if the id of the current thread is on stop_ids :

```
def bot(id):
    global stop_ids
    ...
    q = True
    while q:
        if id in stop_ids:
            stop_ids.remove(id)
            driver.quit()
            q = False
            break
    ...
```